# Why my code can't display the pre_order after deleting a node which had two child nodes?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node
{
    struct node *left;
    int data;
    struct node *right;
};
struct node *fnode = NULL;

void insert(int val)
{
    struct node *ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *parentptr, *nodeptr;
    ptr->data = val;
    ptr->left = NULL;
    ptr->right = NULL;
    if(fnode == NULL)
    {
        fnode = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        parentptr = NULL;
        nodeptr = fnode;
        while(nodeptr!=NULL)
        {
            parentptr = nodeptr;
            if(val<nodeptr->data)
                nodeptr = nodeptr->left;
            else
                nodeptr = nodeptr->right;
        }
        if(val<parentptr->data)
            parentptr->left = ptr;
        else
            parentptr->right = ptr;
    }
}

void pre_order(struct node *tree)
{
    if(tree!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%i ",tree->data);
        if(tree->left)
            pre_order(tree->left);
        if(tree->right)
            pre_order(tree->right);
    }
}

void in_order(struct node *tree)
{
    if(tree)
    {
        in_order(tree->left);
        printf("%i ",tree->data);
        in_order(tree->right);
    }
}

void post_order(struct node *tree)
{
    if(tree)
    {
        post_order(tree->left);
        post_order(tree->right);
        printf("%i ",tree->data);
    }
}

struct node *smallest_element(struct node *tree)
{
    if(tree==NULL || tree->left == NULL)
        return tree;
    else
        return smallest_element(tree->left);
}
struct node *largest_element(struct node *tree)
{

    if(tree== NULL || tree->right==NULL)
        return tree;
    else
    {
        return largest_element(tree->right);
    }
}

struct node *delete_element(struct node *tree, int val)
{
    // some declarations
    struct node *parent, *child;
    child = parent = tree;
    bool doesnt_exist = false;

    // finding the node to be deleted and its corresponding parent
    while(child->data!=val)
    {
        parent = child;
        if(val < child->data)
            child = child->left;
        else
            child = child->right;

        if(child==NULL)
        {
            doesnt_exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if no node exists, print not found
    if(doesnt_exist)
    {
        printf("\nThe node does not exist in the BST.");
        return tree;
    }
    // if node exists
    else
    {
        //if parent node is to be deleted
        if(child==parent)
        {
            //if only parent node exists in the tree
            if(child->left == NULL && child->right == NULL)
            {
                free(child);
                tree = NULL;
                return tree;
            }
            // deleting the parent node and replacing it by left-subtree's highest element
            struct node *temp = tree->left;
            struct node *pre_temp = tree->left;
            //searching for left subtree's max element and its parent
            while(temp->right!=NULL)
            {
                pre_temp = temp;
                temp = temp->right;
            }

            //changing the deleted node's value with left subtree's highest element
            child->data = temp->data;

            //making the ex-position of changed element point to null
            if(pre_temp->right == temp)
            {
                pre_temp->right = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                pre_temp->left = NULL;
            }
            //freeing the ex-position of changed element.
            free(temp);

        }
        else
        {
            // if the node to be deleted has 2 nodes
            if(child->left && child->right)
            {
                //some declarations
                struct node *temp = child->left;
                struct node *pretemp = child;

                //browsing to the maximum node on left subtree
                while(temp->right!=NULL)
                {
                    pretemp = temp;
                    temp = temp->right;
                }

                //exchanging left subtree's max with element to be deleted
                child->data = temp->data;

                //making the temp's parent point to null
                if(pretemp->left == temp)
                    pretemp->left = NULL;
                else
                    pretemp->right = NULL;
                //freeing temp;
                free(temp);
            }
            //if the node to be deleted has only right node
            else if(child->left == NULL && child->right)
            {
                if(parent->left==child)
                {
                    parent->left = child->right;
                }
                else
                {
                    parent->right = child->right;
                }
                free(child);
                return tree;
            }
            // if the node to be deleted has only left node
            else if(child->right==NULL && child->left)
            {
                if(parent->left==child)
                {
                    parent->left = child->left;
                }
                else
                {
                    parent->right = child->left;
                }
                free(child);
                return tree;
            }
            //if the node to be deleted has no children
            else
            {
                if(parent->left == child)
                    parent->left = NULL;
                else
                    parent->right = NULL;
                free(child);
                return tree;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int decision;
    struct node *ptr;
    int ip;
    do
    {
        printf("\n ********MAIN MENU********");
        printf("\n 1. Insert element");
        printf("\n 2. Pre-order Traversal");
        printf("\n 3. In-order Traversal");
        printf("\n 4. Post-order Traversal");
        printf("\n 5. Find smallest element");
        printf("\n 6. Find largest element");
        printf("\n 7. Delete an element");
        printf("\n 8. Exit");
        printf("\nEnter your choice:");
        scanf("%i",&decision);
        switch(decision)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter the element to be inserted:");
                scanf("%i",&ip);
                insert(ip);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(fnode)
                {
                    printf("\nThe pre-order traversal is as follows:\n");
                    pre_order(fnode);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nThe BST is empty!!!");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(fnode)
                {
                    printf("\nThe in-order traversal is as follows:\n");
                    in_order(fnode);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nThe BST is empty!!!");
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if(fnode)
                {
                    printf("\nThe post-order traversal is as follows:\n");
                    post_order(fnode);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nThe BST is empty!!!");
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                ptr = smallest_element(fnode);
                if(ptr)
                {
                    printf("\nThe smallest element is: %i",ptr->data);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nThe BST is empty!!!");
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                ptr = largest_element(fnode);
                if(ptr)
                {
                    printf("\nThe largest element is: %i",ptr->data);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nThe BST is empty!!!");
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("\nEnter the element you want to delete:");
                scanf("%i",&ip);
                fnode = delete_element(fnode,ip);
                break;
        }
    }
    while(decision!=8);
    return 0;
}
```

After I delete a node which had two child nodes, the resultant BST is formed properly (I verified it through debug tools). I have added all the possible cases for deleting a node from BST (has 0/1/2 child nodes and I have handled everything).

But when I make it to print the preorder/postorder/inorder traversal, the program just exits. Can u suggest me why is it so?

Comment: Please post a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, reduce your code to the minimum that can reproduce the problem. For example, remove all the user input code and replace with fixed function calls that sets up the tree to reproduce the problem. As it is, it is too much code for a Stack Overflow question and you have also not provided the exact input.

Comment: Activate and read your compiler warnings. When compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` I see a warning that probably is a bug.